# changing distributions over expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation

I have difficulty understanding Appendix B2 on [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.10837.pdf) (you can directly go to Appendix B2). I'm trying to understand why the authors of the paper changed the distribution from $ x,y|a$ to a composition of expectations over $x | a$ and $y|x,a$ as follows:

$ E_{(x,y|a)}[f(x) -y] = E_{(x | a)}[f(x)E_{(y|x,a)} - E_{(y|x,a)}y] $

I tried to use Bayes rule to find the link between $P(x,y|a)$, $P(x|a)$ and $P(y|x,a)$, But can't find it. Can anyone help with this ?

Thanks,